# build pytrilinos using trilinos version already installed

Tags: python, c++, compilation, trilinos

I have access to a cluster where `trilinos` is already statically built.

Is it possible to build just `pytrilinos` myself linking to those libraries? or the only way is to built all of `trilinos` from source?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is: no.

The installation instructions for PyTrilinos mention that Trilinos should be built with shared libraries.

> options -D Trilinos_ENABLE_PyTrilions:BOOL=ON and -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=ON.

[PyTrilinos installation FAQ](http://trilinos.sandia.gov/packages/pytrilinos/faq.html#configuration)